# Restore Nautilus GUI and disappeared desktop folders

Tags: nautilus, directory, 19.04, desktop-environments

I am a beginner Ubuntu user and I have a problem with Nautilus.

On a fresh Ubuntu install I installed Arduino IDE, Matlab R2019b and put via usb just one external hard disk and my smartphone for a picture transfer. As a result, when on the next day I clicked on the white Nautilus folder icon on the left bar nothing happened, and the desktop folders vanished too.

I can navigate through the folders just with the terminal.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus
```

then log off, then

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

but nothing happened.

I have Ubuntu 19.04 and Nautilus (1:3.32.1-0ubuntu0.19.04.0). What can I do? Waiting for your answers, and best regards.